# Android Studio library error: mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes and @android:style/ missing resources name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-styles

Please excuse for my bad english. I got this Error

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 less... (Strg+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

As you can see:

[Build.gradle(app) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq4Ga.png)

My library:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
implementation('com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20")
compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20")
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

And when I go to styles.xml and enter `style`after `@android:`, I get the the following error message:

> Missing resource name less... (Strg+F1) 
>   Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

As you can see:

[styles.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBjH7.png)

I want to add this code:

```
<style name="ExpandedAppbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title" />
```

I use Android Studio 3.2.1
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 28

AndroidManifest.xml:

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignIn" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".FoodList" />
    <activity android:name=".FoodDetail"></activity>
</application>
```

`

I think that both errors are related. I hope that my Informations are sufficent, and somebody can help me.

If it´s useful: I´m following this tutorial: [YouTube Android Food Order App Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T19qTLVDFV0&t=1290s)

Thanks!!:)

Comment: `<style name="ExpandedAppbar" parent="@android:style/" />` in this line of code, can you type what the parent would be? Just to make sure if the reason can be replicated. There are numbers of reasons why android studio show such error. We need to be very specific on what you're trying to send so we could see. On the other hand, I still see the error when I define parents.

Comment: @Ronan Sorry & thanks! I just corrected!

Comment: `@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Titel` change this to `@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title`. There's a typo? let me know I am here. Also, please provide with your base theme (application them and AndroidManifest.xml code) so we could possibly judge the issue

Comment: @Ronan Yup, typo. Is done. :D

Comment: Did you try running the code? also, throw the AndroidManifest.xml file in your post, else I would probably not be able to help you!

Comment: @Ronan I added the AndroidManifest code. Yes, I run the code. I dont get any error without <style name="ExpandedAppbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title" />. But the library line is still red underlined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

For first issue:

This issue occur because you setting somewhere `26.1.0` as library version and `compileSdkVersion 26`.

If you are using `28.0.0` as your library version then use this library version where it applicable.

Check once in every gradle file that your project have and make `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`

For second issue:

change `minSdkVersion 17` to `minSdkVersion 21`.